# How can I install Ubuntu over Fedora 15 without ending up with redundant options in the bootloader menu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I currently have Windows Vista and Fedora 15 dual booting on my system.  I need to keep my Vista for work related stuff, and as a fairly new Linux user am having problems with drivers in Fedora (Wifi, Sound, WebCam not working).  I have used Ubuntu on another system and find I am more comfortable with it.

I want to install the latest Ubuntu over my Fedora partition, but I don't want the bootloader menu to be populated with 5 or 6 different boot options.

I've read online that you can revert to the original Windows bootloader by using the Windows CD, but I do not have that.

Can anyone guide me on how I can swap Fedora for Ubuntu and not have a GRUB menu full of invalid or left over boot options from having had Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you try Ubuntu (live) and test your hardware as some of the problems you are having may be dependent on the kernel, and not Fedora vs Ubuntu.

Assuming you simply prefer Ubuntu and/or your hardware is working and you wish to install Ubuntu, use the advanced partitioning and install Ubuntu into the Fedora partition(s)

At the partitioning screen choose "Something else"

[image: something else]

On the next screen, "specify partitions manually (advanced)"

[image: specify partitions]

That will replace your Fedora installation with Ubuntu.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall for a graphical walk through.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that Ubiquity 12.04 should be able to replace Fedora and keep your home in one go. I haven't tested it, however. If it does, but still keeps the entries in the grub menu, it's a bug. If you have the chance, please test it and comment. If you can't, say so in a comment and I'll try to find the time to do so before release. No promises.